# Can't Publish to Azure VM from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-virtual-machine, azure-deployment

When I try to publish my web app to an Azure VM, the dropdown is empty.  Why?

[image: publish to vm browse screenshot]

I followed this guide: [Create an ASP.NET VM with WebDeploy](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/create-asp-net-vm-with-webdeploy.md#NewVMInputs).

- I ran the PowerShell script, seemed fine
- I configured the Azure firewall and dns

[image: powershell script screenshot]

[image: Azure Firewall screenshot]

[image: dns name configuration screenshot]

---

How do I troubleshoot this?  What else do I look at?

Comment: are you logged in with the same account on both?

Comment: Both?  @NevilleNazerane.  I have a personal and business account with same email.  Signed to both in VS.  The VM shows up in cloud explorer in personal

Comment: try signing out from your business from VS for now. just to ensure VS is populating the list of VMs from your personal

Comment: after signing out of the business account I now see it!  Not a fix but certainly a workaround. @NevilleNazerane

Comment: on the bright side, you know where the issue is. for the fix, log back in and try selecting your personal account from the dropdown

Comment: If the issue fixed, you can post the solution as an answer to close this case.